# why isnt my arduino working with serial?

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to use a wii nunchuk as a mouse with an arduino. The [project](http://makezine.com/projects/make-33/wii-nunchuk-mouse/) is here.

Here is the error message: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XsV6.png)

If you are wondering why I am not posting this on the page, it is because it is several years old and noone goes on there anymore.

Comment: Please do not add pictures, but text.

Comment: try running the shell as administrator

Answer (score 0):

In your python script, you forgot to initialize the baud rate when defining the serial object "port"

```
# The port to which your Arduino board is connected
port = 'arduino_port'
```

try this instead,

```
# The port to which your Arduino board is connected
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)  
#or whatever your port is called
```